Why are they clicking pictures of Miles Morales in this scene?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Jefferson, a cop, is driving his son, Miles Morales, to school in a car. However, he
stops at one point due to a red signal. People nearby gather around the car and
start taking pictures of Miles:

Why are they clicking pictures of him in this scene?

Miles' school chums are unaware that his father is a copper. At first they just see a young person in the back of the police car, then on closer inspection they realise that it's someone they know.
They're obviously taking photos to share with their mutual associates on social media.

SCHOOL KIDS run alongside the car looking at Miles, who slinks down. They bang on the window, teasing Miles, “you get arrested?!”
...
Jeff stops the car. The teens reach Miles’ window.
TEEN BOY: Yo Miles! You get arrested?
MILES:  (mortified) --Oh my gosh. Don’t cops run red lights?
JEFFERSON: Some do... but not your Dad!
Official Screenplay


Oi, mate, whatcha in da back o' dat constable's cah fer?

@Skooba - E's a cheeky scamp that one and no mistake, guv'nor. I 'ere e thinks e's some kind of spoider.
